# Is it possible to abort an IndexedDB upgrade event?

Tags: javascript, upgrade, indexeddb

I'm trying to implement an IndexedDB interface that allows a user to migrate data from a previous database (DB) version (`oldVersion` detected in `onupgradeneeded` handler, `event.target.oldVersion`) to a recent version (`currentVersion` about to be open), meaning I need to:

1. cancel or abort the `currentVersion` open-operation
2. open the previous DB (`oldVersion` detected in `onupgradeneeded`)
3. read its data
4. close the DB
5. (continue with the normal process of opening a `currentVersion` DB)

I'm having trouble when opening `oldVersion` because I cannot abort (Exception 11) the `currentVersion` upgrade event (it is also [not cancelable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/upgradeneeded_indexedDB)).

> Exception 11: An operation was called on an object on which it is not allowed or at a time when it is not allowed.

Is it possible to somehow cancel or abort the upgrade event for `currentVersion`, in order for me to open the `oldVersion`...?

*Note: ...If not, is there anyother way to migrate data from older versions of a DB that I'm missing?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow cancel or abort the upgrade event for currentVersion, in order for me to open the oldVersion...?

```
var rq = indexedDB.open(name, ver);
rq.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  rq.transaction.abort();
};
rq.onsuccess = function(e) { console.log('THIS SHOULD NOT RUN'); };
rq.onerror = function(e) { console.log('This should run'); };
```

> is there anyother way to migrate data from older versions of a DB that I'm missing?

Usually this is the whole purpose of `upgradeneeded` - during the `verionchange` transaction provided to you, you migrate the data and schema from the old version.

```
var rq = indexedDB.open(name, 2);
rq.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  var db = rq.result;
  if (e.oldVersion < 1) {
    // database didn't exist at all, create new schema
    db.createObjectStore('store2');
  } else if (e.oldVersion < 2) {
    // do the migration - assumes v1 had 'store1'
    var store1 = rq.transaction.objectStore('store1');
    var store2 = db.createObjectStore('store2');
    var r = store1.openCursor();
    r.onsuccess = function() {
      var cursor = r.result;
      if (cursor) {
        store2.put(cursor.value, cursor.key);
        cursor.continue();
      } else {
        // migration done, delete old store
        db.deleteObjectStore('store1');
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Is the `get` in `store2.get(cursor.value, cursor.key);` correct?

Comment: Whoops - `put`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting ```Exception 11``` on ```db.deleteObjectStore``` - guessing it is another context when the cursor is done, the transaction is no longer in `versionchange` mode. Does this make sense?

Comment: (Don't report exception codes. New exceptions don't even have those. Just use the name). You'll need to share your code. In the example I gave, the data migration and store deletion are taking place within the implicit versionchange transaction given in the upgradeneeded callback (i.e. the cursor iteration starts and the cursor callbacks are while the transaction is active)

Comment: The trick for me was using a callback inside the `onsuccess` of the cursor request. Which I was kinda reluctant because my solution was based on promises (openCursor returned a promise, when resolved try to insert data, but it failed). This callback solution works which is basically your solution, so marking this answer as correct. Thx

Comment: Yay, glad we got the problem sorted out. And yeah, Indexed DB and Promises are challenging to get to work together.